# I'd like OS X 10.8 to receive network notifications

Tags: macos, notifications, growl

I've got some shell scripts that can send network notifications to *Growl for Windows*, and it's working fairly well. Can Notification Center on 10.8 (or iOS devices for that matter!) be configured to receive these? Does it even use Growl's layer 7 protocol at all?

Answer (score 3):

[Mountain Growl](https://github.com/stigi/MountainGrowl/) will route Growl notification through Notification Center. This way your scripts could still send the network notifications to Growl and they will show up in Notification Center.